# Android app statisticks

Tags: android, google-play

About 20 hours ago, I published my first android application on Google market. Everything works fine, but I would like to find out If i done something wrong. I can't see statistics for this app: "Sorry, no data for this metric". Is this because of the fact that my app is freshly published, or is it because of code (maybe I have to insert some peace of code in order to enable tracking)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a little longer.  I'm not sure of the exact cycle, but it takes a day or so for the first update.

If its a paid app you can see the number of downloads by looking in your merchant account.